# If $u$ is a weak solution of the Navier-Stokes equations then $\partial_t u \in L^{4/3}(0,T; V^*)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces, fluid-dynamics, bochner-spaces

The following is from the book "The Three-Dimensional Navier-Stokes Equations" by Robinson, Rodrigo, and Sadowski.

For some background, let $H$ be the completion (in the $L^2$ norm) of the space of divergence-free smooth functions with compact support in some bounded set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, and $V = H \cap (H^1_0)^3$. Let $C_{c, \sigma}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ be the set of all divergence free smooth vector fields with compact support. Any norm that has no subscript denotes the $L^2$ norm, $\| \cdot\| = \| \cdot\|_{L^2}$.

They define $u$ to be a weak solution of the Navier-Stokes equations satisfying the initial condition $u_0 \in H$ if

1. $u \in L^\infty(0,T; H) \cap L^2(0,T; V)$ for all $T > 0$ and
2. $u$ satisfies the equation $$\int_0^s -\langle u, \partial_t \varphi\rangle + \int_0^s \langle \nabla u, \nabla \varphi \rangle + \int_0^s \langle(u \cdot \nabla)u, \varphi \rangle = \langle u_0, \varphi(0)\rangle - \langle u(s), \varphi(s)\rangle \tag{3.3} $$ for all test functions $\varphi \in C^\infty_{c, \sigma}$.

In their proof they reference the following:

> **Corollary 1.32** Suppose that $u, g \in L^1(0, T; X)$ and that for every $f \in X^*$ $$\langle f, u(t_2)\rangle - \langle f, u(t_1)\rangle = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \langle f, g(s) \rangle ds$$ for almost every pair $(t_1, t_2)$ with $0 \leq t_1 \leq t_2 \leq T$. Then $\partial_t u = g$ in the sense of Definition 1.30 (which gives the definition for a weak time derivative, which I have omitted in this post).

> **Lemma 3.4** If $u \in L^\infty(0,T; H) \cap L^2(0, T; V)$ then $$(u \cdot \nabla)u \in L^{4/3}(0,T; L^{6/5}).$$

> **Lemma 3.6**  If $u$ is a weak solution of the Navier-Stokes equations then $$\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \langle \nabla u, \nabla \phi\rangle + \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \langle(u \cdot \nabla )u, \phi \rangle = \langle u(t_1), \phi \rangle - \langle u(t_2), \phi \rangle \tag{3.4}$$ for $\phi \in C_{c, \sigma}^\infty(\Omega)$ and almost every $t_2 \geq t_1$, for almost every $t_1 \geq 0$ including $t=0$.

I am having some trouble following their proof of the following lemma:

> **Lemma 3.7** If $u$ is a weak solution of the Navier-Stokes equations then $$\partial_t u \in L^{4/3}(0,T; V^*).$$

Their proof:

> From Lemma 3.6 we have, for almost all $t > 0$ and for every choice of $\varphi \in C_{c, \sigma}^\infty(\Omega)$, $$\langle u(t), \varphi \rangle - \langle u_0, \varphi \rangle = \int_0^t \langle g, \varphi\rangle_{V^* \times V},$$ where $g$ is given by $$\langle g, \varphi\rangle_{V^* \times V} = -\langle \nabla u, \nabla \varphi \rangle - \langle(u \cdot \nabla )u, \varphi \rangle.$$ From our assumption on the integrability of $u$, it follows that $g$ is a bounded linear functional on $V$ for almost all $s$, because $$|\langle \nabla u, \nabla \varphi \rangle| \leq \| \nabla u\| \|\nabla \varphi \|$$ and $$| \langle (u \cdot \nabla) u, \varphi \rangle| \leq \|(u \cdot \nabla) u\|_{L^{6/5}} \|\varphi\|_{L^6} \leq c \|(u \cdot \nabla) u\|_{L^{6/5}} \|\nabla \varphi \|,$$ where we used the estimate in the proof of Lemma 3.4 and the Sobolev embedding $H^1 \subset L^6$.

I am able to follow everything until this point. From here the proof continues:

> Hence, Lemma 3.4 yields $$\|g\|_{V^*}^{4/3} \leq c \|(u \cdot \nabla) u\|_{L^{6/5}}^{4/3} + c\|\nabla u \|^{4/3} \\\leq c \|(u \cdot \nabla )u\|_{L^{6/5}}^{4/3} + c(1 + \|\nabla u\|^2) \in L^1(0,T).$$ It follows that $g \in L^{4/3}(0, T; V^*)$ and using Corollary 1.32 we obtain $$\partial_t u \in L^{4/3}(0, T; V^*).$$

I do not understand much of this part. How do they obtain these bounds for $g$ in the $V^*$ norm, and in particular how does this all follow from Lemma 3.4? How are the terms on the right hand side in $L^1$, and how does that imply $g \in L^{4/3}(0, T; V^*)$? How does Corollary 1.32 lead to the result?

Comment: To get $V^*$ estimates use the Sobolev embedding $H^1 \hookrightarrow L^6$, to see integrability: the rhs is integrable wrt $t$ due to Lemma 3.4 and $u\in L^2(0,T;H^1)$.

Comment: @daw Thank you for your comment. Could you elaborate on how the Sobolev embedding leads to the $V^*$ estimate? We have that $\|g\|_{V^*}^{4/3} = \sup_{\varphi \in V} \Big(\frac{\|-\langle \nabla u, \nabla \varphi \rangle - \langle(u \cdot \nabla )u, \varphi \rangle\|_{V = H^1}}{\|\varphi\|_{L^2}}\Big)^{4/3}$, but how do we use the Sobolev embedding inequality here?

Comment: Estimate each term in $g$ separately. $V \hookrightarrow L^6$ implies $L^{6/5} \hookrightarrow V^*$.

Comment: @daw When estimating each team in $g$ separately we use the triangle inequality to obtain $\|g\|_{V^*}^{4/3} \leq \sup_{\varphi \in V} \Big(\frac{\|\langle \nabla u, \nabla \varphi \rangle\|_{V} + \| \langle(u \cdot \nabla )u, \varphi \rangle\|_{V}}{\|\varphi\|_{L^2}}\Big)^{4/3}$, I assume from here we use sort of Sobolev embedding inequality that you mentioned, but won't the cross terms resulting from the exponent $4/3$ cause some problems?

Comment: You can avoid the cross term using $(a+b)^p \le 2^{p-1}(a^p+b^p)$.

Comment: @daw That is very clever. The problem has now been reduced to $\|g\|_{V^*}^{4/3} \leq 2^{1/3} \sup_{\varphi \in V} \frac{\|\langle \nabla u, \nabla \varphi \rangle\|^{4/3}_{V} + \| \langle(u \cdot \nabla )u, \varphi \rangle\|^{4/3}_{V}}{\|\varphi\|_{L^2}}$. It is not immediately obvious to me where to go from here, but I will try to figure this out. Thank you!

Comment: @daw I tried working out the details but I still am stuck. Could you explain how we bound $2^{1/3} \sup_{\varphi \in V} \frac{\|\langle \nabla u, \nabla \varphi \rangle\|^{4/3}_{V} + \| \langle(u \cdot \nabla )u, \varphi \rangle\|^{4/3}_{V}}{\|\varphi\|_{L^2}}$ by $\leq c \|(u \cdot \nabla) u\|_{L^{6/5}}^{4/3} + c\|\nabla u \|^{4/3}$, and how to then bound this by $c \|(u \cdot \nabla )u\|_{L^{6/5}}^{4/3} + c(1 + \|\nabla u\|^2)$? I don't see how Lemma 3.4 is useful here.