# Trouble bounding a linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces

This is an offshoot of another question I asked ([If $u$ is a weak solution of the Navier-Stokes equations then $\partial_t u \in L^{4/3}(0,T; V^*)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4717082/if-u-is-a-weak-solution-of-the-navier-stokes-equations-then-partial-t-u-in)) which contains all the background information. However here I have tried to omit as many unnecessary details as possible to keep the question more focused.

Let $V \subset H^1$ and $H \subset L^2$ denote function spaces, and let $g$ a linear functional on $V$ defined by:
$$g(\varphi) = -\langle \nabla u, \nabla \varphi \rangle - \langle(u \cdot \nabla )u, \varphi \rangle$$
where $u \in L^\infty(0,T; H) \cap L^2(0,T; V)$ is fixed. I would like to show that $$\|g\|_{V^*}^{4/3} \leq c \|(u \cdot \nabla) u\|_{L^{6/5}}^{4/3} + c\|\nabla u \|^{4/3}_{L^2} \tag{1}$$
$$\leq c \|(u \cdot \nabla )u\|_{L^{6/5}}^{4/3} + c\big(1 + \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2\big) \tag{2}.$$

I have the following two estimates:
$$|\langle \nabla u, \nabla \varphi \rangle| \leq \| \nabla u\|_{L^2} \|\nabla \varphi \|_{L^2} \tag{3}$$
$$| \langle (u \cdot \nabla) u, \varphi \rangle| \leq \|(u \cdot \nabla) u\|_{L^{6/5}} \|\varphi\|_{L^6} \leq c \|(u \cdot \nabla) u\|_{L^{6/5}} \|\nabla \varphi \|_{L^2}. \tag{4}$$

So far what I have is that
$$\|g\|_{V^*}^{4/3} = \sup_{\varphi \in V} \Big(\frac{\big|-\langle \nabla u, \nabla \varphi \rangle - \langle(u \cdot \nabla )u, \varphi \rangle\big|}{\|\varphi\|_{L^2}}\Big)^{4/3} \\\leq \sup_{\varphi \in V} \Big(\frac{\big|\langle \nabla u, \nabla \varphi \rangle\big| + \big|\langle(u \cdot \nabla )u, \varphi \rangle\big|}{\|\varphi\|_{L^2}}\Big)^{4/3}$$
$$\leq 2^{1/3}\Bigg[\sup_{\varphi \in V} \Big(\frac{|\langle \nabla u, \nabla \varphi \rangle| }{\|\varphi\|_{L^2}}\Big)^{4/3} + \sup_{\varphi \in V} \Big(\frac{|\langle(u \cdot \nabla )u, \varphi \rangle|}{\|\varphi\|_{L^2}}\Big)^{4/3}\Bigg]$$
which by (3) and (4) continues as
$$\leq 2^{1/3}\Bigg[\|\nabla u\|^{4/3}_{L^2}\sup_{\varphi \in V} \Big(\frac{\|\nabla \varphi\|_{L^2} }{\|\varphi\|_{L^2}}\Big)^{4/3} + c \|(u \cdot \nabla) u\|^{4/3}_{L^{6/5}} \sup_{\varphi \in V} \Big(\frac{\|\nabla \varphi \|_{L^2}}{\|\varphi\|_{L^2}}\Big)^{4/3}\Bigg]$$
$$= 2^{1/3}\sup_{\varphi \in V} \Big(\frac{\|\nabla \varphi\|_{L^2} }{\|\varphi\|_{L^2}}\Big)^{4/3}\Bigg[\|\nabla u\|^{4/3}_{L^2} + c \|(u \cdot \nabla) u\|^{4/3}_{L^{6/5}}\Bigg] \tag{5}.$$

This is where I am stuck. How do we know that the supremum in (5) is finite? Even if this term was to be proven finite, both terms in the brackets in (5) will not have the same constant as in (1) so I believe I may be making a mistake somewhere. I am also unsure how to obtain (2). Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I noticed a mistake, when calculating the operator norm of $g$ the norm in the denominator should be the $H^1$ norm. Thus (5) should read
$$= 2^{1/3}\sup_{\varphi \in V} \Big(\frac{\|\nabla \varphi\|_{L^2} }{\|\varphi\|_{H^1}}\Big)^{4/3}\Bigg[\|\nabla u\|^{4/3}_{L^2} + c \|(u \cdot \nabla) u\|^{4/3}_{L^{6/5}}\Bigg] \tag{6} $$
Since $\|u\|_{H^1}^2 = \|u\|_{L^2}^2 + \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2$ implies $\|\nabla u\|_{L^2} \leq \|u\|_{H^1}$, we have that
$$(6) \leq 2^{1/3}\sup_{\varphi \in V} \Big(\frac{\|\varphi\|_{H^1} }{\|\varphi\|_{H^1}}\Big)^{4/3}\Bigg[\|\nabla u\|^{4/3}_{L^2} + c \|(u \cdot \nabla) u\|^{4/3}_{L^{6/5}}\Bigg]\\
= 2^{1/3}\Bigg[\|\nabla u\|^{4/3}_{L^2} + c \|(u \cdot \nabla) u\|^{4/3}_{L^{6/5}}\Bigg] \\\leq C \Big(\|(u \cdot \nabla) u\|_{L^{6/5}}^{4/3} + \|\nabla u \|^{4/3}_{L^2}\Big)$$
after choosing $C$ sufficiently large. I think this should be right.

Comment: Your estimate looks good to me. Note that you can alternatively write $\Vert g \Vert_{V^\ast} = \sup_{\varphi\in V, \Vert\varphi\Vert = 1} \vert g(\varphi) \vert$. This way you don't need to carry the norm of $\varphi$ in the denominator with you.

Comment: @stange Thank you. If I may ask two follow up questions, the book I am following then states the following bound $C\Big(\|(u \cdot \nabla) u\|_{L^{6/5}}^{4/3} + \|\nabla u \|^{4/3}_{L^2}\Big) \leq C\|(u \cdot \nabla) u\|_{L^{6/5}}^{4/3} + C(1 + \|\nabla u \|^{2}_{L^2})$. I was able to show this using Young's inequality with $p = 3/2$ and $q = 3$, which I believe is right. They then state that this last inequality is in $L^1(0,T)$, and this implies that $g \in L^{4/3}(0, T; V^*)$. I could not figure out where these last two claims come from. Perhaps I should open this as a new question?

Comment: As $u\in L^2(0,T;V)$, we have $\Vert u \Vert_{H^1}\in L^2(0,T)$, and in particular $\Vert\nabla u \Vert_{L^2}^2\in L^1(0,T)$. Analogously, $u\cdot\nabla u \in L^{4/3}(0,T;L^{6/5})$, hence $\Vert u\cdot\nabla u \Vert_{L^{6/5}}^{4/3}\in L^1(0,T)$. And clearly, $c$ is integrable as $(0,T)$ is finite. And then arguing in reverse, as $\Vert g \Vert_{V^\ast}^{4/3}\in L^1(0,T)$, this implies $g\in L^{4/3}(0,T;V^\ast)$.

Comment: @stange Thank you. Are you using the fact that $(0,T)$ is finite so $u \in L^p$ implies $u \in L^q$ for $1 \leq q \leq p$ to show that every thing is in $L^1(0,T)$?  I am new to Bochner spaces so I am trying to understand the overall logic, is the idea that we have shown that $\Vert g \Vert_{V^\ast}^{4/3}$ is finite and so it belongs to $L^1(0,T)$ since the integral of a bounded function on a fintie domain is finite?

Comment: We don't need to use any embeddings here. Say we have $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, i.e., $\int_\mathbb{R} \vert u \vert^2 \, dx < \infty$, which by definitions means the $u^2\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. For Bochner spaces it's the same argumentation just with the respective norms. And we don't bound $\Vert g \Vert_{V^\ast}^{4/3}$ point wise, as we don't have the information that the right hand side is bounded point wise, but in $L^1(0,T)$, as you said. So we have $\int_0^T \Vert g \Vert_{V^\ast}^{4/3} dt \leq \int_0^T (...) dt$. And as we argued above, the RHS is bounded in $L^1(0,T)$.

Comment: @stange Thank you very much for all your patience, I finally understand everything. Your comments were a huge help!